# QEMU for Win7 hosting Debian : no more able to connect to the network

Tags: windows-7, qemu, tap, bridge

I'm fighting strongly against a problem that is making me crazy.

I’m extensively using QEMU over a Win7 64bits machine for running different Linux VMs (Debian, Raspbian). 
In the past I configured the network following the QEMU instructions using the OpenVPN TAP device and network bridge in Win7 : it ran perfectly and the Linux machine was able to connect the “real world” networks, internet and so on.

In the last few days, on the contrary, this nice behavior stops working. The Windows situation is unmodified (the OpenVPN TAP driver settings are the same, the bridge is still there, when the bridge is active Windows still see the network, the TAP driver becomes “busy” when the QEMU VM starts as usual, the QEMU startup scripts are still the same…), but the emulated Linux system (whatever image I use) is unable to connect the network. 
The “eth0” interface is active but unable to get the IP address from the DHCP and also using fixed IP address doesn’t solve the problem, since the IP address is not seen by the “real” network.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall again the OpenVPN TAP driver,  to downgrade Win QEMU to the previous version, but no way !
The only change that I made in the HOST configuration has been to install GNS3 (with its own TAP driver), but without including the QEMU VM in any GNS3 network.

Does anybody have suggestions regarding what kind of checks  I have to do on QEMU in order to solve the problem ? 
Any help will be appreciated
Regards 
Ugo Poddine

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get out.
I was forced to restore a previous system image : all attempts to uninstall and reinstall the OpenVPN TAP driver were useless.
The problem is probably due to the update of the OpenVPN TAP driver : with the v.9.0.0.9 no problem, but updating to the 9.21.1 seems to have generated the problem.
I'm now able to use again QEMU and GNS3 in network.
But what a strange case !